# vaadin table must sort entries in chronological order descending i.e. latest at the top then down to the earliest notes

Tags: sorting, jakarta-ee, vaadin

I have a vaadin table which is displaying Notes, with created date time. I want to sort entries in chronological order descending (i.e. latest at the top then down to the earliest notes) by default. When I added a new value it should be in top. This is a Java EE web application which is using Vaadin.

I tried ...

```
setSortContainerPropertyId(NoteContainer.DATE_CREATED);
setSortAscending(false);
sort();
```

inside my NoteTable constructor. But it only added the sorting functionality to DATE_CREATED column. when I clicked the that column header only it starts to sort. Please give me a proper solution...?

Note Table class constructor..

```
public NoteTable()
{
    dataSource = new NoteContainer();
    setContainerDataSource(dataSource);

    NoteTableColumnGenerator columnGenerator = new NoteTableColumnGenerator();
    addGeneratedColumn(ACTION, columnGenerator);
    addGeneratedColumn(CREATED_BY, columnGenerator);
    addGeneratedColumn(TEXT, columnGenerator);

    setVisibleColumns(NoteContainer.NATURAL_COL_ORDER);
    setSizeFull();

    Object[] columns = getVisibleColumns();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
    {
        if (((String) columns[i]).equals(NoteContainer.DATE_CREATED))
            setColumnWidth(columns[i], 150);
        else if (((String) columns[i]).equals(NoteContainer.CREATED_BY))
            setColumnWidth(columns[i], 150);
        else if (((String) columns[i]).equals(NoteContainer.ACTION))
            setColumnWidth(columns[i], 150);
        else
            setColumnWidth(columns[i], 550);
    }
    setColumnHeaders(NoteContainer.COL_HEADERS_ENGLISH);

    setSelectable(true);
    setImmediate(true);
    setSortContainerPropertyId(NoteContainer.DATE_CREATED);
    setSortAscending(false);
    sort();
}
```

Note Container class

```
public class NoteContainer extends BeanItemContainer<CaseNote> implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5926608449530066014L;

    public static final String DATE_CREATED = "dateCreated";
    public static final String CREATED_BY = "createdBy";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";
    public static final String ACTION = "Action";

    public static final Object[] NATURAL_COL_ORDER = new Object[] {
        ACTION, DATE_CREATED, CREATED_BY, TEXT

    };

    public static final String[] COL_HEADERS_ENGLISH = new String[] {
        "ACTION", "Date Created/Updated", "Created/Updated By", "Note"
    };

    /**
     * Default Constructor.
     * 
     */
    public NoteContainer()
    {
        super(CaseNote.class);
    }
 }
```

Note : CaseNote is an Entity Class.

Comment: What's the type of "dateCreated" property?

Comment: Thanx for reply. Actually dateCreated is in "Date" format in Entity Class. But inside the NoteTable class it has been converted to a String before displaying it. It is displaying as a Label inside the Column.

Comment: Do you mean that container property is actually `java.util.String` or `com.vaadin.ui.Label`? In those cases container would not be able to sort the column as date by default (in former it would sort lexicographically). You should provide the property as date or implement your own [ItemSorter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/AbstractBeanContainer.html#setItemSorter(com.vaadin.data.util.ItemSorter)) for custom ordering.

Comment: its a `java.util.String`. You mean now its ordering strings right? yea now I got it.. Nwy.. Then can you explain me how to add a custom **ItemSorter** .. Can you give me an example.? Or can we add a sorter when container querying date from the CaseNote Entity? Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by my self..
I added `sort();` inside the table `refresh()` method instead of NoteTable constructor.

Now it is working fine. thank you everyone,  who tried  to help me.. :)